# Add Button to gwt widgets

Tags: java, gwt

How can i add a button without text only with marker for forward and backward action for example for widget ListBox in gwt? i tried something like this:

```
 Button btn = new Button("Forward");
        btn.setHTML(("<img border='0' src='image\\B_forwards.png' />"));
```

but can't get the picture to show on button.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a button. Add an Image widget, and add a ClickHandler to it.

Comment: It would be better if you can provide some links or example for OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add an image to a normal GWT Button, then PushButton is the way to go:

```
PushButton pushButton = new PushButton(new Image("test.png"));
```

Otherwise, if you just want to have a clickable image, you still can do that:

```
public interface MyResources extends ClientBundle{
    MyResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(AppImages.class);
    @Source("image.gif")
    ImageResource image();
}

Image image = new Image( MyResources.INSTANCE.image() );
image.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
         // do whatever you want
     }
} );
```

Comment: i can't see either image, is there in gwt such simple widget markers for forward and backward buttons, where shouldn't be used images?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. Sorry. However I edited my answer to make it clearer. I hope it will help. And I don't think there is predefined widgets for forward and backward buttons in gwt...

Comment: thank you for your response,i have i listbox with elements, and want with help of this forward and backward pointers scroll throw the elements of listbox, like if i press forward it will be choosen the next element in the listbox and if i press backwards it will be choose the previos element in listbox. And about image size should i resize it, or it can be used just as normal size?

Comment: To change row selection (for forward button for instance) I guess can do something like this: theListBox.setSelectedIndex(theListBox.getSelectedIndiex()+1);
And I really don't know about sizing issues... sorry